# How to use ROS without Catkin or rosbuild

Tags: ros, build, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My project currently uses our own build system. We just want some functionality from ROS such as urdf loading.
Can I do that without switching the whole project to the catkin/rosbuild building system.
Is there any guide on this topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220219/how-to-use-ros-without-catkin-or-rosbuild/) by [DamnItROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/24967/damnitros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-10-31

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-11-01**:
You can find a similar question (and answer) [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/212061/make-nodes-without-making-a-package/#212063)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A catkin package is basically a CMake project which can be built without the `catkin` specific tools. Simply invoke the same commands as for any CMake project:

- `mkdir build`
- `cd build`
- `cmake ..` (you might want to pass flags to a) build tests, b) build in release/debug mode, c) choose a custom install prefix)
- `make`
- `make install`

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robarnes](https://answers.ros.org/users/37232/robarnes/) on 2018-08-30**:
Not sure this fully answers the question. Yes, it is straightforward to replace the catkin command line tools. But what about the catkin macros in the CMakeLists.txt itself? E.g. catkin_package(), catkin_python_setup(), etc.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-30**:
Almost every ROS package uses CMake functionality provided by `catkin`. Replacing those with plain CMake would be possible but *a lot of* effort. I don't see why you would want to do that. It would be similar to "how can we get rid of CMake in these packages and build everything using Makefiles".

**Comment by [robarnes](https://answers.ros.org/users/37232/robarnes/) on 2018-08-30**:
Agreed. So let's say my codebase uses a different build system (bazel). I'd like to introduce a dependency on a catkin package Foo. Bazel can build cmake projects, but I'm not sure how catkin fits in. Could I just create a bazel target to build catkin from source, and then have Foo depend on that?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-30**:
`catkin` is simply providing some CMake syntactic sugar. For building you can treat a catkin package just like any other CMake package.